# Tag synonym proposal: "faster" => "speed"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request, synonym-request

[faster](/questions/tagged/faster) seems to have no difference in meaning from [speed](/questions/tagged/speed), which is handily beating it in number of questions and (in my opinion) sounds much better as a tag.

Comment: In our current so-not-so politically correct world, I'd understand why some people would prefer `faster` to `speed`. Obviously there are less drugs involved.

Comment: That interpretation never even occurred to me and I doubt that it could be a real problem.

Comment: @Lance: `synonym-request` doesn't seem to be an existing tag; not sure if that was intentional on your part.

Comment: What about the `performance` tag? It sees far more use than `speed`. Maybe both `faster` and `speed` should be merged into `performance`?

Comment: @Ben, I realized that we needed it, and when I have time will retag other questions with it.  Input is welcome.

Comment: @frederic, `performance` can be measured by more ways than speed, for example, memory usage.  Same thing for `optimization`.

Comment: It appears that [tag:faster] is already a synonym of [tag:performance].  Does it really need another synonym?

Comment: That's been done since I posted this question; there were 101 questions tagged [tag:faster] when I asked. I wonder why this doesn't have a `status-`.

Comment: @Jeff, that wasn't a good synonym for whoever did it to choose, but I guess we have it now.

Comment: @Lance: I agree but unfortunately there wasn't anything else I could have done about that except mention it here.  ;)

Comment: @Jeff, yep, I understand, hopefully someday a moderator will take the task on and clean up all that stuff.  It looks like they just dumped it all in performance without consideration for the other aspects of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I created the [running-time](/questions/tagged/running-time) tag a few years ago, but it looks like [speed](/questions/tagged/speed) has overtaken it.

While I think `running-time` is more precise, I'm not really hung up on which is the 'main' tag.
`Faster` should definitely be synonymed to one of them.